# Which is the best way to express event of button clicked?

Tags: css

Here is my button. When I click it in Firefox it shows some dotted line in it.
But on Chrome it does not show any expression so that user can fill button is clicked.

```
<input type="submit" class="button" onclick="GetSentiment()" id="GetSentiment" value="Get Sentiment" />
```

Can some one let me know any attractive button click event for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/y6XGg/

I tried with gradient but it was on button hover. And could not create appropriate color shading for color in above fiddle. I appreciate if some one can look it.

Comment: Use `outline: 0` for your first question. For the second part, it's primarily opinion based, so I'll leave you to this instead: http://www.bestcssbuttongenerator.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/inoLAfA/2/edit)**

```
.button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: How would keyboard users know where the current focus is after hiding the outline?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Hey thanks, But it does not show any effect when clicked. I checked in both chrome and mozilla

Comment: @Programming_crazy probably cause I removed some CSS of yours. The demo is there just related to your Question-Issue, not to replicate fancy effects.